# cygwin - bash can't find file depending on arguments

Tags: bash, cygwin

If I type `bash -i release_script.sh` it starts processing the script

If I type `bash --login -i release_script.sh` I get the error:

> bash: release_script.sh: No such file or directory

I don't understand why suddenly it can't even *find* the script. Is the error message inaccurate or did I miss something really obvious?

Comment: If you give an absolute path to the script, does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cygwin Bash, you can just call the script directly.

```
$ cd /tmp

$ echo 'echo Hello World!' > hello.sh

$ ./hello.sh
Hello World!
```